# How to explore the attached disc in azure virtual machine

Tags: azure

I attached a disc to existing virtual machine using the attach disc option

However after attaching it, I am not able to find where the newly added storage disc is located in the VM. It still shows only C & D(Temporary Storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to go into Disk Management and initialise the disk, then partition it (Disk Management should detect that there's an uninitialised disk when you first open it and prompt to initialise it).

This is the same process as if you attached a physical disk (that is unformatted) to a physical system.

Comment: thanks Greg, I clicked on initialize, alloted a name, marked it as active and then mapped it to a drive and got it working

Comment: It's a step easily missed if you've never done it before.  Glad you got it working.